# How to convert Quaternions into Polar form?

Tags: quaternions

I would like to know how to write quaternions as polar form. Because I heard that if $A$ and $B$ are elements of $C$, this can be done with the form $A \cdot e^{B \cdot j}$.

But how can I do that?
Can I do it like this

$
\begin{align*}
a + b \cdot i + c \cdot j + d \cdot k &= \sqrt{\left( a + b \cdot i \right)^{2} + \left( c + d \cdot i \right))^{2}} \cdot \exp\left( \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{c + d \cdot i}{a + b \cdot i} \right) \cdot j \right)\\
\end{align*}
$?

Comment: Hint: show that if $b^2+c^2+d^2=1$, then $(bi+cj+dk)^2=-1$. Use that to show that, if $b^2+c^2+d^2=1$, then $$e^{(bi+cj+dk)\theta}=\cos\theta+ (bi+cj+dk)\sin\theta$$

Comment: Thank you! I think that is helpful.

Comment: If you have any questions, please always show us your attempts and thoughts behind the problem so that we can really help you and not just solve the task for you. SE also has quite "high standards", which should also be maintained.

Answer (score 2):

> How to convert Quaternions into Polar form?

In general if you have a quaternion $q$ with $ q = q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} $, you can write it as $ q = \left| q \right| \cdot \exp\left( \theta \cdot \left( \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} + \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} + \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \right) $ where $ \left| q \right| = \sqrt{q_{w}^{2} + q_{x}^{2} + q_{y}^{2} + q_{z}^{2}} $.

We already know from studying [quaternions in spatial rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternions_as_rotations) that $ e^{\theta \cdot \left( u_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + u_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + u_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} \right)} = \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left( u_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + u_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + u_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) $ so we get $ q = \left| q \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left( \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} + \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} + \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \right) $.

If we compare the ral parts of both sides of the equation of the quaternion (the one in the algebraic form and the one in the polar form), we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
q = q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} ~&\wedge ~q = \left| q \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left( \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} + \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} + \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} &= \left| q \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left( \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} + \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} + \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \right)\\
q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} &= \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} + \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} + \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \quad\mid\quad \Re\left(  \right)\\
\Re\left( q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) &= \Re\left( \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} + \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} + \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \right)\\
q_{w} &= \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right) \quad\mid\quad \div \left| q \right|\\
\frac{q_{w}}{\left| q \right|} &= \cos\left( \theta \right) \quad\mid\quad \arccos\left(  \right)\\
\arccos\left( \frac{q_{w}}{\left| q \right|} \right) &= \arccos\left( \cos\left( \theta \right) \right)\\
\arccos\left( \frac{q_{w}}{\left| q \right|} \right) &= \theta\\
\theta &= \arccos\left( \frac{q_{w}}{\left| q \right|} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

So all we have to do is $ \varphi_{x} $, $ \varphi_{y} $ and $ \varphi_{z} $ determine.
In fact, we can do this with all components of the quaternions:
$$
\begin{align*}
q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} &= \left| q \right| \cdot \left( \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left( \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} + \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} + \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \right)\\
q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} &= \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \quad\mid\quad \dot\Im\left(  \right)\\
\dot\Im\left( q_{w} + q_{x} \cdot \mathrm{i} + q_{y} \cdot \mathrm{j} + q_{z} \cdot \mathrm{k} \right) &= \dot\Im\left( \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \varphi_{x} \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \varphi_{y} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) + \left| q \right| \cdot \cos\left( \varphi_{z} \right) \cdot \mathrm{k} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \right)\\
q_{a} &= \cos\left( \varphi_{a} \right) \cdot \sqrt{\left| q \right|^{2} - q_{w}^{2}}\\
q_{a} &= \cos\left( \varphi_{a} \right) \cdot \sqrt{\left| q \right|^{2} - q_{w}^{2}} \quad\mid\quad \div \left( \sqrt{\left| q \right|^{2} - q_{w}^{2}} \right)\\
\frac{q_{a}}{\sqrt{\left| q \right|^{2} - q_{w}^{2}}} &= \cos\left( \varphi_{a} \right) \quad\mid\quad \arccos\left(  \right)\\
\arccos\left( \frac{q_{a}}{\sqrt{\left| q \right|^{2} - q_{w}^{2}}} \right) &= \arccos\left( \cos\left( \varphi_{a} \right) \right)\\
\arccos\left( \frac{q_{a}}{\sqrt{\left| q \right|^{2} - q_{w}^{2}}} \right) &= \varphi_{a}\\
\varphi_{a} &= \arccos\left( \frac{q_{a}}{\sqrt{\left| q \right|^{2} - q_{w}^{2}}} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

> Can I do it like this $ a + b \cdot i + c \cdot j + d \cdot k = \sqrt{\left( a + b \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)^{2} + \left( c + d \cdot i \right))^{2}} \cdot \exp\left( \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{c + d \cdot \mathrm{i}}{a + b \cdot i} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} \right) $?

Nope, because the formula is unfortunately not correct.
You can easily disprove the formula with the simple counterexample $ a = 0 = b $:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\text{counterexample } a = 0 = b\\
&\quad 0 + 0 \cdot i + c \cdot j + d \cdot k = \sqrt{\left( 0 + 0 \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)^{2} + \left( c + d \cdot i \right))^{2}} \cdot \exp\left( \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{c + d \cdot \mathrm{i}}{0 + 0 \cdot i} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} \right)\\
&\quad 0 + 0 \cdot i + c \cdot j + d \cdot k = \sqrt{\left( 0 + 0 \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)^{2} + \left( c + d \cdot i \right))^{2}} \cdot \exp\left( \tan^{-1}\left( \underbrace{\frac{c + d \cdot \mathrm{i}}{0}}_{\text{Division by } 0 \text{ is not defined!}} \right) \cdot \mathrm{j} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
But of course also bring quaternions into the polar form $ A \cdot e^{B \cdot \mathrm{j}} $ ([*which is discussed here*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.0852.pdf)).